# regex to capture text from multiple lines in Ansible

Tags: regex, ansible

from the text below, I would like to capture text starting from "this" till i find the first "!" ( the one before east coast)

I am using regex /^this.*>!/ which works if the below shown text is in stdout format..but it doesn't work when it is in stdout_lines. I am using regex_search on ansible to for this

```
this device version

  1.2.3 network systems

  new york rhode island

  new england Connecticut

!

east coast cities

!
```

Comment: Ansible supports `multiline` for `regex_search`, e.g. `{{ 'foo\nBAR' | regex_search("^bar", multiline=True, ignorecase=True) }}`. See [Filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html).

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing ansible but reading what you want to achieve, I recomment you to use:

`/^this[^!]*/s`

`^this` looks for the string 'this' at the beginning

`[^!]*` looks for zero or more characters which are not a '!'

`/s` allows you to search over multiple lines

Comment: Thanks. looks like the regex_search function in Ansible can only grep one line.  need to find a way to iterate the regex for each line.